# How to create a set of Questions and Subquestions with order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database of Questions and Subquestions (which belong to 1 Question). I want the subquestions to be ordered inside each question.

Also, I want a bunch of main Questions to be ordered among themselves. One way to do it will be to add an Order column in Question and Subquestion table and fill it in manually. But, since this DB can be very dynamic, this is not a viable option.

So, what I want is

```
1. Root Q1
    a. Sub1_Q1
    b. Sub1_Q2
2. Root Q2
    a. Sub2_Q1
    b. Sub2_Q2
    c. Sub2_Q3
```

I have seen gems like `ancestry` and `acts_as_tree`. While it is possible to create a parent child relationship there, there is no scope to order a bunch of siblings.

Comment: Is there any reason for you not to associate these two table models?  Whereby Question would `has_many` subquestions and Subquestion would `belong_to` one question?

Comment: Yes, I would associate them. But, how would I create an order.?

Comment: You could do smth like `default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }` inside your model file for Subquestions. This would order your subquestions in descending order. This is what is called a scope with stabby lambda. You can order them however you want however.

Comment: ActiveRecord or Mongoid ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have Question model which has many subquestions (SubQuestion model). And you need to order questions by created_at DESC and subquestions by created_at ASC(in each question).

So the models will look like:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subquestions, -> { order("created_at ASC") }
end
class SubQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Now you just do:

```
@questions = Question.order("created_at DESC").preload(:subquestions)
```

This will result next query:

```
SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions"  ORDER BY created_at DESC
SELECT "subquestions".* FROM "subquestions" WHERE "subquestions"."question_id" IN (...)  ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

This way when you'll be iterating within each question within each subquestion of the question, you will have the right order of both - question and subquestion.

Answer (score 0):

While it is better to sort directly with a DB query like in intale's solution, you mentionned a dynamic DB (Mongoid ?) and maybe you just can't do that.

You can still sort the items you're showing "manually" (assuming `score(q)` is a function that computes the score of a question/sub_question)

*question_controller.rb*

```
def index
  # Eager_loading to avoid other queries
  # You can replace .all by anything else (like by .page(params[:page]) if you use kaminari)
  @questions = Question.includes(:subquestions).all.to_a.sort { |q1, q2| score(q1) <=> score(q2) }
end
```

*views/questions/index.html.erb*

```
<% questions.each do |q| %>
  <!-- Question Stuff -->
  <% q.subquestions.sort{ |q1, q2| score(q1) <=> q2} %>
    <!-- Subquestion stuff -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It is much slower than a DB ORDER_BY, and absolutely inadapted for alot of data, however you can use any piece of code as the `score` function